# MySQL join/subquery where results are filtered by multiple values of foreign table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date, join

I have two tables:

- user
- user_action

The user_action table has the following attributes:

- id
- user_id
- type
- timestamp

I have two different types of actions:

- opened message
- received message

Now my question is: how do I make query such that I will get all the users that have opened a message within the last month but disclude all the users that have received a message within the last 2 days?

I think this can be done with some form of a join and then using WHERE NOT IN with a subquery but that does not sound very effective so I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Please show us the expected Output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally tend to use `JOIN`s instead of `EXIST`/`NOT EXIST` subqueries.

Here is an approach using a self-`LEFT JOIN` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    user_id
FROM
    user_action ua
    LEFT JOIN ua2 
        ON  ua2.user_id = ua.userid
        AND ua2.type = 'received message'
        AND ua2.timestamp > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
WHERE 
    ua.type = 'opened message'
    AND ua.timestamp > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    AND ua2.user_id IS NULL
```

Details :

- the `ua1` searches for users having opened messages within the last month, using the `WHERE` clause
- `LEFT JOIN ua2` optionnaly tries to find a received message for the same user within the last two days
- `WHERE ... ua2.user_id IS NULL` removes records for which a such message happened (ie for which the `LEFT JOIN` was successful)
- `SELECT DISTINCT` avoids duplicated output rows when a given user has more than one received message within the last month